# Excel dna based addin disappears from Excel Ribbon

Tags: excel

Excel dna based addin disappears from Excel Ribbon ocassionally; expecially when user lock the computer and comes back and dont see add in in ribbon.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: You need to check that none of your ribbon callback functions are throwing an unhandled exception. You can start by wrapping all of them with exception handlers that just log the exception somewhere.

Comment: this happens when user goes out and lock the screen and then come back; their addin is disappeared from Excel. It disappears even when it is not running...

Comment: If you can make a simple add-in that exhibits this behaviour, you can send it to me. General support for Excel-DNA is better on the Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna